# How to scale x-axis with intervals of 1 hour with x data type being timedelta64[ns]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotnine

My x-axis being time in hours and minutes, I am not able to plot in intervals of 1 hour, by default it is plotting in interval of 5 hours.

Here x-axis is "newtime" which is in the format below

```
 00:00:00
 00:15:00
 00:30:00
 00:45:00
 01:00:00
 01:15:00
 01:30:00
 01:45:00
 02:00:00
 02:15:00
 02:30:00
     .
     .
     .
 23:45:00
```

First tried like this but got error

```
ggplot(data = temp1)+
aes(x="newtime", y="SALES" ,color="newdate")+
geom_line()+
labs(x = "Time", y = "SALES", title = s)+
scale_x_datetime(breaks="1 hour")
```

TypeError: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Second tried like this but got error

```
ggplot(data = temp1)+
aes(x="newtime", y="SALES" ,color="newdate")+
geom_line()+
labs(x = "Time", y = "SALES", title = s)+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=range(0,24,1))
```

TypeError: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Third tried like this but got error

```
ggplot(data = temp1)+
aes(x="newtime", y="SALES" ,color="newdate")+
geom_line()+
labs(x = "Time", y = "SALES", title = s)+
scale_x_discrete(breaks=range(0,24,1))
```

TypeError: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

```
ggplot(data = temp1)+
aes(x="newtime", y="SALES" ,color="newdate")+
geom_line()+
labs(x = "Time", y = "SALES", title = s)
```

The entire code is here

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *
import numpy as np

temp1=pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\2019\\DATA.xlsx")
a=temp1.Date.astype(str)
temp1["newdate"]=a
b=pd.to_timedelta(temp1.Hour, unit='h') + pd.to_timedelta(temp1.Min, 
unit='m')
temp1["newtime"]=b
v=(
 ggplot(data = temp1)+
 aes(x="newtime", y="SALES" ,color="newdate")+
 geom_line()+
 labs(x = "Time", y = "SALES", title = "s")+
 scale_x_datetime(breaks="1 hour")

  )
print(v)
```

And the data is in the link [link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/70s2oeg8ugc5khc/DATA.xlsx/file)

I'm trying to plot something like this !https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOMRE.jpg. I'm getting plot like this !https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr9cb.jpg.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which would include a sample dataframe to demonstrate the problem. Without that, I can only assure you that `scale_x_datetime` works for me.

Comment: This still does not make a reproducible example. What is `s`? What type are your data? How do you create the data frame?

Comment: Hi @krassowski The post has been edited.Please let me know if you are able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Still, works for me. You may need to provide a reproducible (like in copy-paste runnable) example (plus possibly versions of plotnine/pandas/numpy).

Comment: Installed pandas version - '0.24.1', numpy - '1.16.1', plotnine - '0.5.1'. For same code I am getting error, snaps of code and error provided in the below link. [link](https://imgur.com/a/Is6pWJX)

Comment: Hi @krassowski I have edited the post, the entire code and dataset is provided. Please let me know if you are able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Posted an answer below. Let me know if the solution works for you!

Answer (score 3):

When using `timedelta` dtype you need to use scale for this type: `scale_x_timedelta`. However, this may require some tricks to specify breaks, e.g.:

```
scale_x_timedelta(
    breaks=lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(
        pd.Series(range(0, 10)),
        unit='h'
    )
)
```

Which looks like this:

[image: using deltatime]

Alternatively, you could keep using `scale_x_datetime`, converting your `newtime` column:

```
temp1.newtime = pd.to_datetime(temp1.newtime)
```

And if you want to have nice labels, use mizani formatters:

```
from mizani.formatters import date_format

v = (
    ggplot(data=temp1)
    + aes(x="newtime", y="SALES", color="newdate")
    + geom_line()
    + scale_x_datetime(
        breaks="1 hour",
        labels=date_format('%H:%M') # for nice labels
    )
)
print(v)
```

And here is the result:

[image: using datetime]